# Net::SSH::Expect interactive session

Tags: perl

I want to login to remote server and execute a file called welcome.pl. This welcome.pl file would require me to enter username and greet me with the username i entered.

I have a small code snippet which is failing.

```
use Expect;
use Net::SSH::Expect;
  my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
        host => "omsas",
        user => 'root',
        raw_pty => 1
    );

$ssh->run_ssh() or die "SSH process couldn't start: $!";



my $mkdir = $ssh->exec("mkdir security");
$ssh->exec("cd security");


$ssh->exec("perl welcome.pl") or die "Cant execute";
$ssh->waitfor('You are in OMSAS server now. Enter username',1) or die "waited enopugh";
```

However my code fails at the last line. Could anyone please help me here??

welcome.pl is a simple 3 liner where i print the welcome msg and ask for username and print it back..

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails'? It does not compile? It times out? It runs away with its girlfriend?

Comment: Well it throws the error which i have mentioned after die, i.e "waited enought"

Comment: Remove the `or die` part after it and follow the line with: `print $ssh->before();` What does that say? It should give you anything in the stream so we can see whether the server replies at all.

Comment: Its empty!! Returns / prints nothing.

Comment: And how about `print ssh->exec("perl welcome.pl")`;`?

Comment: Yes, i get the output now. However i am sure if i will be able to interact. Let me have a quick check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42177/discussion-between-jigar-and-devadder)

Comment: I am not used to ssh::expect. I guess you should be able to communicate with the script now, using `$ssh->send()` and any of the reading methods like `waitfor()`. Just one suggestion: Use the third argument of `waitfor()` in your question you used your input as a regex while apparently thinking it would be matched as a literal string (not escaped .).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear people from the future:

It turns out, the first output of a script started via `exec()` is found only as a return value of the `exec()` and not in the input stream. Basically `exec()` acts like a `send()` followed by a `read_all()`. Despite that, interaction with the started script is possible later via `send()` and any of the reading methods like `read_all()` or `waitfor()`.

Pseudo-Code:

```
my $firstResponse = $ssh->exec("script.pl");
$ssh->send("What i tell the script.");
my $whatTheScriptAnswers = $ssh->read_all(1);
.
.
.
```

I used `read_all(1)` to make `read_all()` return only after one second of inactivity to not miss anything. Note that `read_all()` will return everything that would appear on the remote console, not necessarily only the output of the one script, if there was other stuff running.